# Posting HTML forms from other forms

Tags: html, forms

For layout reasons, I have to separate the "submit button" of a form from it. So I made the form fields in form1 and the submit button in form2, How can I make the submit button of form2 post the data in form1?
[image]

the publish button is form2, how can I make it send the data of the form1 ( the fields under ) using only HTML.

Comment: Why would you have the publish button before any of the controls in the form you want to submit? It just forces users to scroll back up to the top! For that matter, why do you have more than one form on that page in the first place? I can only see one in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the form attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form).

```
<input type="submit" form="id_of_the_form_it_should_submit">
```

(NB: [Limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/forms))

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery, to submit it. [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: From the question: "using only HTML"

Comment: Yes I know that, But I want to use html only, for now.